# What is the difference between Anypoint Management Center and Mule Management Center?

Tags: mule

What is the difference between Anypoint Management Center and Mule Management Center? why are two names given? Is it based on the release versions?

Answer (score 5):

Mule Management Console (not Center) or MMC will be replaced by Anypoint Management Center (AMC) in the future.

But the name AMC will be replaced or AMC will be part of ARM, Anypoint Runtime Manager, more info about that:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/managing-applications-and-servers-in-the-cloud-and-on-premises

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/biz/mule/anypoint-runtime-manager-v1-2-monitoring-servers-and-apps-with-splunk-elk/

https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/sending-data-from-arm-to-external-monitoring-software#basic-architecture

The current status is that you can use MMC for On-Premise (On-Prem) ESB only but the new solution will be ARM, for CloudHub it's already the case.

In the future for On-Prem ESB you will have two options, manage your ESB On-Prem via an On-Prem ARM or via the cloud.